# Display a lot of images in background (SVG)

Tags: html, svg

I would like to display, in SVG, a lot of circles. Each of us would contain an image.

I've found a way for doing that. I define a pattern :

```
<defs>
        <pattern preserveAspectRatio="true" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" height="1" width="1" y="0" x="0" id="imageExample">
            <image height="1" width="1" y="0" x="0" xlink:href="img/imageExample.png"/>
        </pattern>
</defs>
```

And then I display the circle :

```
<circle cx=x cy=y r=r stroke="white" stroke-width="2" fill="url(#imageExample)"/>
```

My question is : is it necessary to define 1000 patterns if I want to display 1000 circles ?

[edit] I want that each circle has a different background image, sorry.

Comment: Try on a smaller scale with 2 or 3 images and tell us how it goes.

Comment: Are the patterns unique? If so, then yes. If not, you only need one pattern. I'd also suggest [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) to manipulate the 1000 circles, see their [collission](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/collision.html) example.

Comment: What do you mean by "unique" ? The background images are unique. Is it time-expensive to define a lot of patterns ?

Answer (score 1):

of course, i isn't. see the demo below, also avaliable [online](http://collapsar.co.ohost.de/data/so.1kcircles.svg):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174765/display-a-lot-of-images-in-background-svg  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   version="1.1"
   width="20cm" height="20cm"
   viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"
   preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"
   style="background-color:white; border: solid 1px black;"
>
    <defs>
            <pattern preserveAspectRatio="true" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" height="1" width="1" y="0" x="0" id="imageExample">
                <image height="1" width="1" y="0" x="0" xlink:href="img/imageExample.png"/>
            </pattern>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="123" cy="109" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="url(#imageExample)"/>
    <circle cx="456" cy="332" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="url(#imageExample)"/>
    <circle cx="12"  cy="444" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="url(#imageExample)"/>
    <circle cx="77"  cy="567" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="url(#imageExample)"/>
    <circle cx="66"  cy="712" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="url(#imageExample)"/>
    <circle cx="47"  cy="855" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="url(#imageExample)"/>
    <circle cx="843" cy="30"  r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="url(#imageExample)"/>
    <circle cx="112" cy="321" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="url(#imageExample)"/>
    <circle cx="387" cy="543" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="url(#imageExample)"/>
    <circle cx="444" cy="67"  r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="url(#imageExample)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This will show the same image in every circle - it's not 100% clear from the question, but I don't think this is what the OP is aiming for.

Comment: @Adrian good point, might be. different background patterns require different definitions unless they functionally depend on each other, so i thought the OP's problem was not being sure how to reuse the pattern.

Comment: As Adrian said, my goal is to show a different image in each circle. Is it not possible without defining a lot of patterns ? If no, is it time-expensive to define a lot of patterns ?

Comment: @Arnaud you can instantiate a svg/xml template (precomputing), should be able to define the pattern src image with js (i haven't tried this) or define the src of the pattern as a (parameterized) url calling a script, letting the server deliver different pics (i have done this albeit not in the context of svg).

Comment: I've not all understood, sorry. But thank you for your help, I will re-read this later. (if you modify your answer, I would accept it)